# PHP - Concatenate if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation

I want to concatenate in the middle of an echo to write an if statement, is this possible? Here is what I have.

```
echo "<li class='".if ($_GET["p"] == "home") { echo "active"; }."'><a href='#'>Home</a>        </li>";
```

Comment: You want [a ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  `echo "<li class='". (($_GET["p"] == "home") ? "active" : "") ."'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>";`

Comment: Why am I getting voted down?...What about this question isn't defined?

Comment: I didn't do it but I guess it's because it's something you could have found the answer to by googling.

Comment: Well I came where I trust peoples opinion. Thats not cool lol.

Comment: echo is a language construct. it is not a function and has no return value that you could concatenate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this, using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
echo "<li class='". (($_GET["p"] == "home") ? "active" : "") . "'><a href='#'>Home</a>        </li>";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "<li class='".(($_GET["p"] == "home") ? "active" : "")."'><a href='#'>Home</a>        </li>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

```
echo "<li class='".($_GET["p"] == "home" ? 'active' : '') ."'><a href='#'>Home</a>        </li>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messy inline concatenations, might I suggest getting cozy with [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)?

```
$format = '<li class="%s"><a href="#">Home</a>        </li>';
printf($format, ($_GET['p'] == 'home') ? 'active' : '');
```